# A data structure similar to a HashMap with more than one "distinct" value

Tags: java, hashmap

Is there any similar data structure that stores a key and unlike a `HashMap<Key, Value>` it stores more value regarded to a single key? If not, any suggestion for doing so? Because making several HashMap with same key and different values does not look so neat.

**EDIT**
When I said more than one value, I mean distinct value. For example, consider a map that has a key for each person and we wish to store persons Name and address and phone number.

Answer (score 1):

Check [`Guava's Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) ! It let you have multiple values for the same key.

#### Example

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

multimap.put("Fruits", "Banana");
multimap.put("Fruits", "Apple");
multimap.put("Fruits", "Pear");
multimap.put("Vegetables", "Carrot");

// Getting values
Collection<string> fruits = myMultimap.get("Fruits");
```

[`Guava`](https://github.com/google/guava/) is a really useful library for java programmer you should definitely check it out !

### Edit

Well after you edit you really just need a simple `HashMap<Key, Person>`. You can define your `Person` class like this:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Person(String name, String address, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Use your `HashMap<Key, Person>` where `Key` could be a `String` for example:

```
Map<String, Person> personMap = new HashMap<String, Person>();

personMap.put("patrick_key", new Person("Patrick", "1000 Notre-Dame street", "123456789"));
personMap.put("stephan_key", new Person("Stephan", "2000 Notre-Dame street", "987654321"));
```

then you can access `Patrick` like that:

```
Person person = personMap.get("patrick_key");
```

Comment: What you mean by distinct value? Why don't you just use a `Person` object? Just make a simple `HashMap<String, Person>` for example.

Comment: I feel HashMap looks easier to access and I guess it must be faster?

Comment: how about this case, we do not know that a person has only a phone number, maybe has two or more phone numbers. or maybe has more than one adr? home adr and work adr and other possible adr. so is there anyway to make the number of instances for phone (or any of those values) , dynamic?

Comment: @seventeen Just make another constructor or use default constructor with setters.

Comment: imagine in the run-time, we realize how many numbers he has and then we want to enter that specific numbers to the HashMap.

Comment: @seventeen You'll get the person from the map with his key and set the phone number with the setter. Just search for java setter on google. Consider accepting my answer.

Comment: @seventeen You would then use a collection of strings instead of a single string. Regardless of how much information you want to have in the Object it's still just an object.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit you probably want to still store a single Value for each Key but make the value an Object. For example

```
public class PersonInfo {
     private String name;
     private String address;
     private String phoneNumber;
     etc...
}
```

and define your map as `HashMap<Key, PersonInfo>`

Comment: imagine in the run-time, we realize how many numbers he has and then we want to enter that specific numbers to the HashMap

Comment: @seventeen You would then use a collection of strings instead of a single string.  Regardless of how much information you want to have in the Object it's still just an object.

Comment: @seventeen in that case, `PersonInfo` should have a `private List<String> phoneNumbers`.  The `HashMap` doesn't have to be aware of that, it's a property of the person that they have zero or more phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hashmap and each "value" is a list (linked or double linked on the basis of your needs).

Comment: How about create a new class that groups all the values you need? Because in OO programming it has no sense store separately values that belong to the same conceptual object

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this is to create some form of PersonInfo object, then map that value along with the key String. When you want to call the distinct key, you can just retrieve the object which contains any value you wish to describe about that person.

If you then want them to be distinct, you can record each phone number on a separate list and any time the user inputs a number, you can just check it against the global list of numbers.
(address/name's can be used twice because they're fairly common ie. think Junior and Senior living in the same home)